I can't see my dataverse tables created in a power Apps solution when I use a Power Platefrom dataflow
In fact, I created a solution on power apps in which I created .
Then, when creating an analytics dataflow, I used the Dataverse connector via the get Data option to connect to the dataverse.
However, I see tables but not the one I created in my solution, nor even the one created outside the solution.
I don't know what I've missed, but if anyone has encountered this problem or can help me understand, I'd be delighted.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
